# unable to retrieve data from database only printing try and catch block

Tags: java, jdbc

not able to  retrieve data from oracle database and deployment assembly not shown in eclipse only try and catch block is printing!!

```
package jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.Statement;

import java.sql.ResultSet;




public class Demo 
{

public static void main(String[] args)
 {

 String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE";

 String un="system";

 String pw="system";

 Connection con=null;

 Statement stmt=null;

 ResultSet res=null;

try {

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

    System.out.println("driver successfully loaded");

    DriverManager.getConnection(url,un,pw);

    System.out.println("connection establshed succesfully");

    String s="SELECT * FROM VTURESULTSJAN ";

    stmt=con.createStatement();

    res=stmt.executeQuery(s);

    while(res.next()==true)

    {

        String a=res.getString(1);

        String b=res.getString(2);

        int c=res.getInt(3);

        int d=res.getInt(4);

        int e=res.getInt(5);

        System.out.println(a+""+b+""+c+""+d+""+e);

    }

}
catch(Exception e)

{

    System.out.println("some problem occured");

}

}

}
```

//output;driver successfully loaded

connection establshed succesfully

some problem occured

Comment: catch block is not just to print some message, the purpose of this block to get the exception and perform something accordingly. Also, it is useful to know the exact exception, which is occured.

Comment: Could you place `e.printStackTrace();` in your catch block and let us know the output?